# Exception occurring if search box (with suggestions) is used too quickly

Tags: winjs

I add search suggestions to my search box like so...

```
var s = document.querySelector(".win-searchbox");
s.addEventListener("suggestionsrequested", function (e) {
    e.detail.searchSuggestionCollection.appendQuerySuggestions(["one", "two", "three"]);
});
```

But when I run the app and use the search field too quickly, it throws one of two exceptions deep in the ui.js file having to do with adding to and removing from the suggestions list. I assume that the async script is trying to access list items that are taken out of existence already (because I'm navigating quickly... search, enter, type a new search, enter, etc.).

I can't figure out how to debug this or find a way around it. Is there a null check or something that I need to put somewhere? Thanks.

Comment: do you have only one search box in the whole app? `this.element.querySelector` might be better. assume this code is in page ready handler. is searchSuggestionCollection empty when handler is called second time, good to check. does this repro only if you do it at speed or otherwise also?

Comment: it might be good to compare with a working piece of code and then, localize the problem. i see that there is a [sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/SearchBox-control-sample-0f64f94d/sourcecode?fileId=86727&pathId=26249260) here. does this also have the same issue?

Comment: Thanks, @Sushil. I've give those a try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was the page was navigating back to itself when the query was submitted, so I searched too quickly it tried to do navigations overlapped somehow and threw the exception. The fix was to simply replace the filter function on the ListView when the query was submitted. Obviously, this is the better way to do it anyway and the performance was dramatically improved.

Answer (score 0):

I had an issue similar to this with the search box control if I searched rapidly to navigate to the search results page.  My suggestions are ranked values from a 40K of JSON objects, and the result returns within 100ms.  I made a global variable to hold the search promise and canceled it in my navigation onnav event.